# React waiting for map function before deciding render to prevent div flash

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs

I am having a bit of trouble preventing a div flash where react will render the error message then receive props and finally render the props.

In my `EventsView` component I have the following.

*view.js*

```
var view;
if (_.size(this.props.events) !== 0) {
view =  this.props.events.map(function(year) {
                return <YearView year={year} />;
        });
} else {
    view = <NoEventsView />
}
```

So the variable `view` is rendered, initially there is no `this.props.events` on page load as I have another part of the file creating it. The moment this.props.events is created the events are rendered. This is done throught a `react.Backbone` mixin.

I have tried doing something used some of the component lifecycle methods such as `componentWillUpdate`. The problem is they don't seem to want to work the way I want them to work and the error message is never rendered. Example of what I have tried (among others) below

I thought of doing something like this.

*view.js*

```
componentWillUpdate: function(nextprops, nextstate) {
if (_.size(nextprops.events) !== 0) {
    var view =  nextprops.events.map(function(year) {
                    return <YearView year={year} />;
            });
    this.setState({
        view: view
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        view: <NoEventsView />
    })
}
},

// render this.state.view
```

I would then set the `getInitialState:view` to the a `this.props.events` map.

***EDIT - A temporary and terrible workaround ***

So the problem I was having was I had a top level component accepting a single prop which was a global variable like so

*view.js*

```
React.render(<EventsView events={theseEvents} />, document.getElementById('mainContent'));
```

`theseEvents` is actually a Backbone Collection global variable initialized in another file.

On document load `theseEvents` would be unpopulated so my view would flash with the `<NoEventView />` and then rerender when `theseEvents` is then populated. This is handled by the backbone mixin shown below.

Dan's solution pointed me in the right direction. I set a global variable `window.hasEvents` to true or false depending on what I got back from my ajax request but by that time React was already rendering (the component would start as `hasEvents` would be true, by the time it's finished `hasEvents` might be false). Even if I made `hasEvents` a prop of `<EventsView />` react wouldn't rerender when it changed.

So as a temporary workaround I have defaulted `hasEvents` to true and rendered `EventsView`. I then waited for the component to load and checked whether it was in sync with hasEvents. shown below. Honestly this workaround is not very pleasant.

*view.js*

```
ar EventsView = React.createBackboneClass({
mixins: [
    React.BackboneMixin("events", "all")
],

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        hasEvents: window.hasEvents
    }
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    var model = this;
    // This waits after component loading to check whether hasEvents is the same
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!(model.state.hasEvents == window.hasEvents)) {
            model.setState({
                hasEvents: window.hasEvents
            })
        };
    }, 1000);
},

render: function() {
    var view;
    if (this.props.events.length > 0) {
        view =  this.props.events.map(function(year) {
                        return <YearView year={year} />;
                });
    }
    if (!this.state.hasEvents)  {
        view = <NoEventsView />
    }
    return {
        // other parts of the page were also rendered here
        {view}
    }
});
```

essentially `componentDidMount` waits for a while after component mounting and then double checks a global variable. Definitely not a great workaround especially since it relies on a 1 second `theseEvents` population and it only works on the initial component mounting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second approach is not “the React way” (although technically it may be working) because you shouldn't put React elements into state. Only data should go there, and in `render` if need to figure out how that data corresponds to DOM stucture. It's also best to avoid `state` unless absolutely necessary.

That being said, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Assuming you want to prevent "No Events" flash before events come through, the only way your component can do that is by *knowing* that data is being fetched. If, in addition to `events` prop, you pass `isLoading` boolean prop, you can do that:

```
render: function () {
  var isEmpty = this.props.events.length === 0;
  if (isEmpty) {
    return this.props.isLoading ?
      <p>Loading...</p> : // note you can also return null here to render nothing
      <NoEventsView />;
  }

  return this.props.events.map(function (year) {
    return <YearView year={year} />;
  });    
}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried something similar, the problem Im facing is `this.props.events` updates because it's a backbone mixin linked to a global variable (the component that's doing all this rendering is top level and has no parent - just one prop). When I create window.isLoading and update the variable at various stops along the creation of this.props.events react doesn't rerender when I pass it in as a prop.

Comment: You can amend your Backbone model to have `isFetching()` method. Otherwise I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, can you reproduce it on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) so I could take a look?

Comment: Okay so I decided I am not happy with my workaround I rephrased the question and you can see my current workaround.

Comment: @Deepak But why do you want to have a global `window.hasEvents` instead of `collection.isFetching()` which would trigger Backbone change events?

Comment: That's pretty much the solution I am using now thank you, my collection returns a boolean if it is in the process of fetching.

Answer (score 3):

Since I do a request right when my app starts to check if the user is Authenticated this is how I've been handling it within my components. The parent components state is linked to my store, and it passes down `authenticated` as a property.

I set the components `hasUpdated` state to false initially, since it will receive props from the parent I wait until `componentWillRecieveProps` is triggered and then set `hasUpdated` to `true` since it means our call has returned. Then it renders the elements it needs to.

Not sure if this is the best approach but it has worked for our needs so far.

```
var SomeComponent= React.createClass({
        displayName: 'SomeComponent',
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                hasUpdated : false
            };
        },
        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {
                authenticated : false 
            };
        },
        componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
            this.setState({ hasUpdated : true });
        },
        render: function() {
            var AuthElement;

            if(this.state.hasUpdated){
                if(this.props.authenticated){
                    AuthElement= <div>Authenticated</div>;
                }else{
                    AuthElement= <div>Not Authenticated</div>;
                }
            }

            return (
                {AuthElement}
            );
        }
    });
```